# Invalid file object using sub process communicate python in linux

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I am trying to run a command in python that runs an executable and then I want to get the log file.
I used `subprocess.popen` and then I used `subprocess.communicate` but got the error: Invalid file object.
Here is my code:

```
command = "%s -s/test_scripts/tests/unit_tests.csh list_tests=yes list_groups=yes" % (PATH)
    print(command)
    os.popen(command)
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    try:
        text = p.communicate(timeout=600)[0]
```

Here is the error message i got:

```
 File "/disk/incam/test_scripts/run_all_tests-linux.py", line 249, in <module>
    text = p.communicate(timeout=20)[0]
  File "/opt/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 933, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "/opt/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1666, in _communicate
    selector.register(self.stdout, selectors.EVENT_READ)
  File "/opt/lib/python3.7/selectors.py", line 352, in register
    key = super().register(fileobj, events, data)
  File "/opt/lib/python3.7/selectors.py", line 238, in register
    key = SelectorKey(fileobj, self._fileobj_lookup(fileobj), events, data)
  File "/opt/lib/python3.7/selectors.py", line 225, in _fileobj_lookup
    return _fileobj_to_fd(fileobj)
  File "/opt/lib/python3.7/selectors.py", line 40, in _fileobj_to_fd
    "{!r}".format(fileobj)) from None
ValueError: Invalid file object: <_io.BufferedReader name=4>
```

If anyone knows how to solve this i would love to hear. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you calling both `os.popen()` and `subprocess.Popen()` with the same command?  That makes no sense.  The error you posted clearly did not come from the exact code you posted, so we can only make wild guesses as to what went wrong.  Perhaps you called `.communicate()` more than once on the same `Popen` object?

Comment: @jasonharper what's wrong calling `.communicate()` more than once, if the `communicate()` method timed out? The documentation suggests that this should be fine ...

Comment: there's a chance you're hitting the following bug: https://bugs.python.org/issue35182.